# Efficient partitions in Parquet

Tags: sql, hive, databricks

I'm attempting to put a significant amount of data into Parquet format, but I'm having trouble optimizing this. I cannot seem to optimize using `optimize table_name` because it is not a delta table

> AnalysisException: db.table_name is not a Delta table

I'm creating as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {click_table}  
(
    event_header_event_id string,
    event_date string,
    keyword string,
    ..
using parquet partitioned by (event_date, keyword);
```

I'm inserting as:

```
insert into table {click_table} partition (event_date, keyword) 
(
  event_header_event_id 
, event_date 
, keyword 
...
) 
select 
  cs.event_header_event_id as event_header_event_id
, try_cast(concat(cs.year, "-", cs.month, "-", cs.day) as string) as event_date
, keyword
from db.other_table cs;
```

Searches will happen on both `keyword` and `event_date`, so hence these are as partitions. Need to optimise for fast lookup for queries based on these fields ideally. Any insight into managing these partitions?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Databricks: Yes.

Comment: @DBA_player, Please explain what you want to achieve. Is the problem that writing is too long, or reading takes too long? Or do you want to use Delta format instead of Parquet?